# What's wrong with my session? When I reload the page it says it has a redirect loop

Tags: php, mysql, session

When I reload the page it says : This webpage has a redirect loop.  What is wrong with my code? could somebody help me please.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(sql);
$login_session = $row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
    mysql_close($connection);
    header("Location: AdminLogin.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when redirects circles around.

for example:

```
in index.php the user gets redirected to login.php
in login.php the user gets redirected to register.php
and finaly
in register.php the user gets redirected to index.php again
                                            so that the circle is closed.
```